# Get history of all files in a project

Tags: asp.net, version-control, tfs

I have a helper project where the whole system depend on it, to avoid versioning problems on production server, I need to check that, all source files in the project is no older than 15 days ago, how to do that without viewing the history for each cs file under the project.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Source Control Explorer. Select a folder, right click and start the "View history" command.

You will now see a recursive list of changes.

Comment: Team Explorer in case of VS2010 Professional